# Comparing tuples in a stored procedure and write differences into a diff table

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to compare certain objects serialized to a database. For any such comparison, I know the IDs of two such objects. Let's call them `o1` and `o2`.

A table `X` with columns `A`, `B`, and `C` contains tuples that are linked to `o1` and `o2`, respectively. Thus, each row in `X` is identified by its parent (`o1` or `o2`) and an `ID` column unique among all rows that belong to the same parent.

The comparison of `o1` and `o2` is done by finding items in `X` that exist only for `o1` or only for `o2` (equality of items assumed based upon their local `ID`), and by finding pairs of items for which at least one of them columns `A`, `B`, or `C` has different values. For each difference, a row needs to be added to a `Diff` table.

**My goal is to use a stored procedure to conduct this comparison.**

For each item in `X`, the `Diff` table can receive any number of rows. Therefore, I think an `INSERT ... SELECT ...` statement is not the right way to go. (At least I do not see how to proceed using one.)

Instead, it seems I have to implement this comparison somehow "procedurally", by "manually" comparing column by column, after an outer join. Thus, I have started like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Compare (@o1 INT, @o2 INT) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @o1x INT; @o2x INT;
    DECLARE @o1A INT, @o2A INT;
    DECLARE @o1B INT, @o2B INT;
    DECLARE @o1C INT, @o2C INT;

    DECLARE XCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT x1.ID,
               x1.A,
               x1.B,
               x1.C,
               x2.ID,
               x2.A,
               x2.B,
               x2.C
        FROM X x1 FULL OUTER JOIN X x2 ON x1.ID = x2.ID
        WHERE x1.PARENT = o1 AND x2.PARENT = o2;

    OPEN XCursor

    WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM XCursor INTO @o1x,
                                     @o1A,
                                     @o1B,
                                     @o1C,
                                     @o2x,
                                     @o2A,
                                     @o2B,
                                     @o2C
        IF @@fetch_status <> 0 BREAK

        IF @o1x IS NULL
            INSERT INTO Diff (Object, DiffDescription) VALUES (@o2x, 'O1 X is missing');

        IF @o2x IS NULL
            INSERT INTO Diff (Object, DiffDescription) VALUES (@o1x, 'O2 X is missing');

        IF @o1A <> @o2A
            INSERT INTO Diff (Object, DiffDescription) VALUES (@o1x, 'A is different.');

        IF @o1B <> @o2B
            INSERT INTO Diff (Object, DiffDescription) VALUES (@o1x, 'B is different.');

        IF @o1C <> @o2C
            INSERT INTO Diff (Object, DiffDescription) VALUES (@o1x, 'C is different.');
    END

    CLOSE XCursor

    DEALLOCATE XCursor
END
```

*(This is not guaranteed to be 100% syntactically correct already. I am trying to illustrate the general idea.)*

My question is: **This seems really cumbersome and hard to maintain<sup>1</sup>. Is there a more concise way of conducting this comparison, especially a typical pattern normally employed for such use cases?**

Obviously I have heavily anonymized and generalized my example DB schema and code. In the actual code, there are not just three columns `A`, `B`, and `C`, but more like 20; there is not just one table `X`, but further sub-elements linked from `X`, and the `Diff` table is quite a bit more elaborate and requires more detailed data. The actual code that I have for now is accordingly more complex.

<sup>1</sup>: For instance, it is possible more columns get added to `X` later on. Also, it is possible the structure of `Diff` gets revised in the future. Furthermore, all of this might need to be translated to a different SQL dialect once other DB vendors are targeted.

EDIT: As an alternative for the full outer join, I could also use an inner join there and detect `X` rows that are only present for either `o1` or `o2` separately. Not sure if that would be better performance-wise; at least, it would remove the necessity to suppress the column-based comparisons when only one object was found, which the current source code I posted does not do yet.

EDIT2: To repeat, and clarify: The `Diff` table must receive a row for *each* difference among a pair of equivalent `X` rows. Not just one row for the first detected difference, but one row for each detected difference. If the two `X` rows have different values in columns `A` and `C`, I *two* rows must be created in `Diff` with the appropriate messages. This is the really tricky part, and the one aspect that means I cannot just filter the set of `X` pairs.

Comment: err... why not use a left join?  or a regular join -- if you have a loop in SQL it is 99.99999% likely you are doing it wrong.

Comment: oh I see you used a full outer join -- I'll write you some code....

Comment: You might be able to come up with a lengthy select based on a bunch of UNION ALLs and some CTEs, and insert from that.  That would probably be more efficient, though less intuitively clear.

Comment: @AnnL why would you need UNION ALL?

Comment: @Hogan As a replacement for the OP's many `IF`s. Implement them as queries looking for a specific condition, with the relevant descriptive text, and `UNION ALL` them together so they can be inserted-from in one go.  `UNION ALL` vs. `UNION` so you don't have to waste time resolving duplicates that won't be there.

Comment: @AnnL Not really now SQL works.  You have to use sets when you work with SQL to get all results at once.  As you can see in my answer, a few ORs in the WHERE statement and a CASE and I get the same results.

Comment: @AnnL.: Note that the generated entries for the `Diff` table can never be duplicates, based upon their contents.

Comment: could you provide us some sample data? would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my test data:

```
CREATE TABLE #X
(
    PARENT  TINYINT,
    ID TINYINT,
    A VARCHAR(10),
    B VARCHAR(10),
    C VARCHAR(10)
)

CREATE TABLE #DIFF
(
    OBJ TINYINT,
    DIFF_DESC VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #X (PARENT,ID,A,B,C)
VALUES
(1,1,'ValueA','ValueB','ValueC'),
(2,1,'Value A','Value B','Value C')
```

solution: i created a temp table for each "object" and then started to compare those:

```
SELECT  ID, A, B, C
INTO    #o1
FROM    #X
WHERE   PARENT = 1

SELECT  ID, A, B, C
INTO    #o2
FROM    #X
WHERE   PARENT = 2

--check if one of them is not existing
INSERT INTO #DIFF (OBJ,DIFF_DESC)
SELECT  ISNULL(#o1.ID,#o2.ID), 
        CASE WHEN #o1.ID IS NULL
            THEN 'O1 X is missing'
            ELSE 'O2 X is missing'
        END
FROM    #o1 
        FULL JOIN #o2 ON #o1.ID = #o2.ID
WHERE   #o1.ID IS NULL
        OR #o2.ID IS NULL

-- Just a check, if one the two objects does not exist 
-- (@@ROWCOUNT>0), then there will be no check for A,B,C
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #DIFF (OBJ,DIFF_DESC)
    SELECT  ISNULL(#o1.ID,#o2.ID),
            'A is different'
    FROM    #o1 
            INNER JOIN #o2 ON #o1.ID = #o2.ID 
    WHERE   #o1.A <> #o2.A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  ISNULL(#o1.ID,#o2.ID),
            'B is different'
    FROM    #o1 
            INNER JOIN #o2 ON #o1.ID = #o2.ID
    WHERE   #o1.B <> #o2.B
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  ISNULL(#o1.ID,#o2.ID),
            'C is different'
    FROM    #o1 
            INNER JOIN #o2 ON #o1.ID = #o2.ID 
    WHERE   #o1.C <> #o2.C
END
```

result:

[image: result]

please be aware of this:

- A,B,C are NOT checked if one of the two objects does not exist
- you can add a check, if #o1 and #o2 are empty your table does not containt any data for this PARENTS

Comment: This is similar to the answer I have come up with. I have not used any temporary tables, but rather connected the different expressions by means of some CTEs, but in all, @AnnL provided [the right clue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41597134/comparing-tuples-in-a-stored-procedure-and-write-differences-into-a-diff-table/41597805#comment70398320_41597134). Sorry for not being fast enough at providing some test data, but I see you created quite a suitable minimal test case yourself in the end.

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler if there is a value for the column that will never occur -- in the examples below I use `-1` you could use `'<null>'` for strings.  You don't say which are ids and which are strings

```
SELECT
  x1.ID as ID,
  x1.A as x1_A, x1.B as x1_B, x1.C as x1_C,
  x2.A as x2_A, x2.B as x2_B, x2.C as x2_C,
  CASE
    -- I don't bother to check for the NULLS as a specific case but you could add in those 
    -- before these tests if you wanted to show them.
    WHEN ISNULL(x1.A, -1) <> ISNULL(x2.A, -1) THEN 'A column does not match'
    WHEN ISNULL(x1.B, -1) <> ISNULL(x2.B, -1) THEN 'B column does not match'
    WHEN ISNULL(x1.C, -1) <> ISNULL(x2.C, -1) THEN 'C column does not match'
  END as REASON
FROM X x1 
LEFT JOIN X x2 ON x1.ID = x2.ID
WHERE 
      x1.PARENT = o1 
  AND x2.PARENT = o2
  AND (
       ISNULL(x1.A, -1) <> ISNULL(x2.A, -1)
    OR ISNULL(x1.B, -1) <> ISNULL(x2.B, -1)
    OR ISNULL(x1.C, -1) <> ISNULL(x2.C, -1)
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) make it sound as if only one `WHEN` in a `CASE` directive gets selected. I'll try tomorrow at work, but will your code generate *two* diff entries when a given `x1` and `x2` have different values for, say, `A` *and* `B`? Other than that, the column aliases like `x1_A` appear to remain unused and I'd probably have to check for existence of x1 and x2 separately, given that your `LEFT JOIN` would not return all "outer" x values, right?

Comment: That is correct, only one will be selected -- it was not clear in your question you needed multiple entries in your quesiton -- is this a hard requirement?  It will make the solution much more complicated.

Comment: Yes, that's a hard requirement. That's why, in my attempted solution, I issue an `INSERT` to the `Diff` table for each difference that I find, even among the same pair of `x1`/`x2` tuples. It's also why I wrote "For each item in `X`, the `Diff` table can receive any number of rows." - "any" means 0..n, not 0..1. I know it's tricky, hence my asking here :/

Comment: @O.R.Mapper -- I'll write a new answer with this requirement -- just give me a few minutes.  No loop needed in SQL ever.